# Why does python shared memory implicitly unlinked on exit?

Tags: python, linux, shared-memory, python-3.8

I wrote the following simple program to try shared memory in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

from multiprocessing import shared_memory
from time import sleep

PATH='/pth'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(PATH)
    sleep(10)
```

The issue is that on the program termination I got the following warning:

```
$ /usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:203: 
   UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked shared_memory objects 
   to clean up at shutdown `warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '`
```

And after program exit the shared memory file dissapeared. Why does this happen and how to avoid the shared memory file unlink?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the unlink? Most use cases where you'd want behavior like that are use cases `multiprocessing` wasn't designed to support.

Comment: @user2357112 Because the memory is written by one another process and might be read by multiple other processes. If unlink happens the other couldn't read it anymore.

Comment: You don't have any other processes here. If you had actually created any other processes, the resources wouldn't be cleaned up until all processes involved were done with the shared memory. (You'd still get the warning, though, because you're not calling `close` or `unlink`.)

Comment: If you're trying to communicate with processes that weren't created by `multiprocessing`, well, `multiprocessing` wasn't designed for that. If that's your use case, then you should use something else.

Comment: @user2357112 If another process written in C created a shared memory file and just don't expect it to be deleted by any other process

Comment: @user2357112 https://bugs.python.org/issue46888 there's a bug report related to this behavior

Comment: That's an entirely different issue, triggered by entirely different actions, with an entirely different root cause. That issue is about shared memory being freed after all processes `close` it, due to Windows API behavior. You're not calling `close` at all, and you're not on Windows either.

Comment: @user2357112 Anyway, is it documented somewhere that `unlink` what be implicitly called if it's not called explicitly? The behavior seems not obvious

Comment: @user2357112 It's a bug https://bugs.python.org/issue38119

Answer (score 0):

It's a [BUG](https://bugs.python.org/issue38119). To resolve this issue the following hack might be used:

```
def remove_shm_from_resource_tracker():
    """Monkey-patch multiprocessing.resource_tracker so SharedMemory won't be tracked

    More details at: https://bugs.python.org/issue38119
    """

    def fix_register(name, rtype):
        if rtype == "shared_memory":
            return
        return resource_tracker._resource_tracker.register(self, name, rtype)
    resource_tracker.register = fix_register

    def fix_unregister(name, rtype):
        if rtype == "shared_memory":
            return
        return resource_tracker._resource_tracker.unregister(self, name, rtype)
    resource_tracker.unregister = fix_unregister

    if "shared_memory" in resource_tracker._CLEANUP_FUNCS:
        del resource_tracker._CLEANUP_FUNCS["shared_memory"]
```

After this the code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_shm_from_resource_tracker()
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(PATH)
```

does not implicitly unlink the shared memory